# CollectionView.Refresh() slowed down mysteriously

Tags: wpf

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` in the view model and a `CollectionView` to filter the elements of the collection. I now made a change: I declared the view model as `IEnumerable<T>` and hand out the Enumerator of the `ObservableCollection` in `GetEnumerator()`. And the `DataGrid` is now bound to the view model itself. Here is the construction:

```
public class ViewModel : ModelBase, IEnumerable<Person>
{
    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() => Employees.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Employees.GetEnumerator();

    private ObservableCollection<Person> employees = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Employees { get => employees; set => SetField(ref employees, value); } ...
```

What happens is that `CollectionView.Refresh()` is considerably slower after the change. I have created a demo program showing the effect. The program has two `DataGrids` the same data (Employees).

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
        Content="Run"
        Click="RunCommand"
        />
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
        Text="{Binding Message}"
        />
    <DataGrid
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Height="400"
        />
    <DataGrid
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding }"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Height="400"
        />
</Grid>
```

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;

        int max = 1_000_000;
        for(int i=0; i< max; i++)
        {
            vm.Employees.Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "Walter_" + i.ToString(),
                Lastname = "Winter_" + i.ToString(),
                Age = i
            });
        }
    }

    private void RunCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.MinAge++;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        vm.EmpView1.Refresh();
        long t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        
        sw.Restart();
        vm.EmpView2.Refresh();
        long t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        
        vm.Message = $"{t1} - {t2}"; 
    }
}

public class ViewModel : ModelBase, IEnumerable<Person>
{
    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() => Employees.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Employees.GetEnumerator();

    private ObservableCollection<Person> employees = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Employees { get => employees; set => SetField(ref employees, value); }
    
    private string message;
    public string Message { get => message; set => SetField(ref message, value); }
    public CollectionView EmpView1 { get; private set; }
    public CollectionView EmpView2 { get; private set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; } = 0;
    public int MaxAge { get; set; } = 100;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        EmpView1 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Employees) as CollectionView;
        EmpView2 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this) as CollectionView;
        EmpView1.Filter = Filter;
        EmpView2.Filter = Filter;
    }

    public bool Filter(object o)
    {
        Person p = o as Person;
        return p.Age > MinAge && p.Age < MaxAge;
    }
}

public class Person : ModelBase
{
    private string firstname;
    public string FirstName { get => firstname; set => SetField(ref firstname, value); }

    private string lastname;
    public string Lastname { get => lastname; set => SetField(ref lastname, value); }

    private int age;
    public int Age { get => age; set => SetField(ref age, value); }
}

public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return;
        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is it slower when the `CollectionView` is defined on the view model as opposed to defining it on the `OberservableCollection`? And: how can I fix this?

Comment: An ObservableCollection is a materialized collection with a `Count` property. An `IEnumerable` is just a sequence with an unknown length that needs to be enumerated before you can determine the count.

Comment: Thanks mm8. Any idea what I can do. `Count` is defined in my view model but that is not sufficient. Would I need to implement a specific interface such that it is fast?

Comment: What's the problem with returning a collection instead of an `IEnumerator`?

Comment: I have several collections and depending on the situation I want to return one of them.

Comment: So make a property that returns a collection based on your "situation" then?

Comment: I found another solution. I keep one ObservableCollection and copy the other collections into that. When using a temp collection no events are fired and it's fast enough. I am still curious why my view model is slower when handing out the Enumerator of the internal ObservableCollection. But that's curiosity only, as of now.